# Find maximum $p$ so random variable is in $L^p$ using Laplace transform

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables, laplace-transform

For a (non-negative) random variable $X,$ define its Laplace transform as
$$\mathbb{E}(e^{-\lambda X}) =: L(\lambda),$$
for $\lambda > 0.$ We know that this uniquely determines the law of $X$ as long as $X \geq 0.$ Furthermore, by taking series expansions of the exponential function, we can calculate moments of $X$ from the derivatives of $L$ and evaluating these at $0.$

What property of $L$ will give us the maximum $p$ so that $X \in L^p(\mathbb{P})?$

Comment: well for $X$ non-negative I'm pretty sure saying $X\in L^P(\mathbb{P})$ is the same thing as saying the $p$th moment of $X$ exists.  So it seems you would need to know how to find the largest finite moment of $X$ using $L$, but I don't know how you do that.